# What is the .srr extension used for when coupled with an .avi file?

Tags: avi, divx, xvid

I've just noticed them more recently; does anyone know what the `.srr` extension is used for? I always find them with `.avi` files (encoded as DivX or Xvid). I tried searching the usual extension sites but couldn't find a definition that looks valid for this context... Perhaps I didn't look hard enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are related to "Scene releases". SRR files are created by [ReScene](http://rescene.info/).

### [FAQ](http://rescene.info/faq.htm)

> What is this .srr file?
>
> The .srr file is the format used by ReScene. It contains backups of all parts of the RAR files that are not the actual archived data. It can also store any other miscellaneous release files (e.g. SFV, NFO, etc). It is also an extensible format that will allow for other uses in the future.

Comment: Ah, so it's nothing to do with the `.avi`, so to speak?

Comment: No - well not directly. If all you do is play the AVI, you will not need to worry about the .SRR file

Answer (score 4):

The old site with info and downloads is down. (rescene.info, rescene.com)

Now you can find all relevant information here: http://rescene.wikidot.com/

A database of SRR files can be found here: http://www.srrdb.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can pack your movie file to exact format of source [XViD/x264 (warez) scene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_(warez)) release. SRR stands for *Scene Release **Reconstruction***
For example you have a different size  video files with 2 hrs 10 mins total Length in folder named

```
PluralSight.Android.Apps.with.Kotlin.Custom.Views-BOOKWARE-KNiSO\
```

After your process it with ReScene/pyReScene and compatible SRR
you will have exact (passing SFV CRC check) [scene release](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_(warez)) files as they were 27-02-2019 pred by kNiSO [scene release group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_(warez)), i.e. 20 splitted RAR parts named:

```
aawkcv.rar  15,000,000
aawkcv.r00  15,000,000
aawkcv.r01  15,000,000
...
aawkcv.r17  15,000,000 
aawkcv.r18  9,489,469
```

and 383,313,920 bytes sized `aawkcv.iso` packed inside them.